# DNS Redirect to another Domain without a server backing it

Tags: php, html, apache, dns

I have 2 Domains. One Domain without web-hosting (lets call it a.com) the other one with web-hosting (lets call it b.com). I want to redirect a.com to b.com/dir (masked) and also while still being able to use URL-Parameters. I tried it as a frame, but that does not work that great on mobile phones, with unmasked redirecting I cannot pass URL-Parameters.

Do you have any way to get this working?
Thanks in andvance.

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding a CNAME record from a.com pointing to b.com but directory masking may not work here. For directory masking your only option would be to use a custom external domain forwarding service (which would be like having a hosting for a.com). Try the CNAME method first and let me know. If this doesn't work I'm really curious to know how else this might be possible.

Comment: Your answer was downvoted because it looked more like an attempt to promote links to your website than an answer. Since you've edited that out I've removed my downvote (should say, this comment is in response to the edit summary asking why)